# How to delete Like elements in Lists in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
List=[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
```

From the above list, I want to delete the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and the 5th, 6th, 7th and so on until I get a list [1,2,3]. If the list doesn't stop at 3 but continue, how should I delete all the other elements?

Comment: Does it need to stay a list? Making it a set gets rid of all duplicates, and even as a set, you can make it a list again,

Comment: Hello Davy M, if I make it a set will it get rid of the duplicate elements?

Comment: `list(set(List))` will return unique list

Answer (score 3):

To remove duplicates and retain the order, you could use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
l =[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
new_l = [a for a, _ in itertools.groupby(l)]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

However, if you are looking for a way to remove all duplicates, rather than long runs of the same value, use an empty set and for-loop:

```
new_l = {}
for i in l:
   if i not in new_l:
      new_l.add(i)
```

Comment: You could also use a set to keep track of what has been seen, since set lookup is `O(1)`: `seen = set()
new_l = []
for i in l:
    if i not in seen:
        new_l.append(i)
        seen.add(i)`

Comment: @RoadRunner great idea, please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 2):

If your list is ordered, you can do like this:

```
my_list = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]

sorted(set(my_list))
```

if the order does not matter:

```
list(set(my_list))
```

*Thanks @ RoadRunner in the comments for the assist from `sorted(list(set(my_list)))` to `sorted(set(my_list))`*

Comment: You can also just do `sorted(set(my_list))` here. No need to wrap `list()` if you apply `sorted()` to a set.

Answer (score 1):

```
def removeDuplicates(arr, n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return n

    temp = list(range(n))

    j = 0;
    for i in range(0, n-1): 
        if arr[i] != arr[i+1]:
            temp[j] = arr[i]
            j += 1

    temp[j] = arr[n-1]
    j += 1

    for i in range(0, j):
        arr[i] = temp[i]

    return j
```

To call:

```
lst = [1,1,2]
removeDuplicates(lst, len(lst))
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to convert the list into a set, which will remove the duplicates for you.  Converting the set back to a list might make it easier for you to manipulate.

```
List = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
List = list(set(List))
```